# WPF - Problem showing a symbol from a custom font

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts

I have a custom font. The font contains symbols at specific addresses. I want to display one of the symbols in a TextBlock.

The font (ttf-file) is located in my applications's folder `Fonts`. I have included the font in the application and set the `BuildAction` to `Resource`.

## XAML

I load the symbol from a specific "address" in the font.

But my application is unable to show the symbol. Instead I see a [single empty square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1qig.png).

Here is my code. Notice the *style* and two *TextBlocks*.

```
<Window x:Class="Main.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Main"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="Foo">
            <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="pack://application:,,,/Main;component/Fonts/#MyFont" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text="&#xE905;" Style="{StaticResource Foo}" />
        <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Text="&#xE777;" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

- I'm sure I load the font correctly in the style.
- The font's name is correct. (Actually, the font's name is the same as the font's file name).
- The first TextBlock is where I try to load the symbol from the font.
- I know that the address `E905` is correct.
- The second TextBlock is just for comparison. With a built-in font and to verify that the syntax to load a symbol at a specific address is correct. (You should be able to copy that line into any WPF-application).

## Try in code

I have also tried this with the code-behind.

Adding the `Loaded event` and added *one more* `TextBlock` with a the name `txt`.

```
<Window x:Class="Main.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Main"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Loaded="Window_Loaded"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="Foo">
        <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="pack://application:,,,/Main;component/Fonts/#GuardTools-Symbol-Bold" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <TextBlock Text="&#xe905;" Style="{StaticResource Foo}" />
    <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Text="&#xE777;" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="txt" />
</StackPanel>
```

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    txt.FontFamily = new FontFamily("pack://application:,,,/Main;component/Fonts/#GuardTools-Symbol-Bold");
    txt.Text = "\xe905";  // &#xe905
}
```

Same problem...

What could be the problem?

*I have also installed the font on my computer, but with no success.*

Comment: Are you sure `TextBlock` are using [TextElement.FontFamily](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.documents.textelement.fontfamily)? I'd try [TextBlock.FontFamily](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textblock.fontfamily).

Comment: If you can install the font on the client pc then this is advisable. There's a memory leak associated with all relative addresses for fontfamily. And that is a relative address. Unless your url starts c:\ then it'll be relative.

Comment: Seeing as how you have a  textblock you're explicitly setting style on I would think defining a fontfamily as a resource and setting the textblock fontfamily to that directly would be clearer than what you're doing there.

Comment: `TextElement.FontFamily` definitely works. Make sure that `MyFont` is actually the font name, and that `Main` is the name of the assembly. Or just write `pack://application:,,,/Fonts/#MyFont`.

Comment: As I wrote in my question: The path and name of the font should be correct. I have check a couple of times.

Comment: If you "*also installed the font on [your] computer*" it may only be a wrong unicode code point, i.e. E905. Did you try any other?

Comment: Yes, I have tried other "addresses". I also have a html-page which reads the same font and from the same address reads the symbol successfully.

Comment: It could be worth trying to do the same logic from code, just as a debugging tool. It would be easier to inspect things, step-trace, etc. and see where it is failing.

Comment: I have now altered my first post with this logic from code to achieve this. Same problem...

Answer (score -1):

I am not pretty sure this could be the root cause of the problem but, can you try to use `TargetType` property in your Style like this:

```
<Window.Resources><Style x:Key="Foo" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="pack://application:,,,/Main;component/Fonts/#MyFont" />
    </Style></Window.Resources>
```